# scheme string-append? recursion to replicate a string

Tags: scheme, racket

Design a program called string-dup that consumes a String s and a Number n and returns a String that is the concatenation of s n times with spaces between each instance of s, i.e.,

(string-dup "a" 3) => "a a a"
Without using replicate but i guess we can use string-append.

So far i got

```
(define (string-dup s n)
(cond 
  [(zero? n) ""]
  [else
   (cond
     [(= n 1 ) s]
     [(> n 1 )(string-dup (string-append s " ") (sub1 n))])]))
```

However, this only allows me to have one string "a". I know when in the list case you can do

```
(cons s (string-cp s (sub1 n)))
```

but how to apply in this case? Thanks.

Comment: I don't recognise the computer language you are using - it's not "string" as you have tagged.

Comment: @WeatherVane Scheme. i think my problem is the recursion in this case. The output returns me the space rather than s " "

Comment: If `string-append` can take 3 arguments instead of just 2, maybe something like this will work: `(string-append (string-dup s (sub1 n)) " " s)` I don't know if it's correct (I suspect it's not quite right), but the basic idea is to try using `string-append` as your outer function.

Comment: @ooga !!!thanks! I didn't come across that thought. I guess i will give a shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recursive call to `string-dup` needs to be a parameter to `string-append`, not the other way round. Here's a corrected (and refactored) version:

```
(define (string-dup s n)
  (cond 
    [(< n 1) ""]
    [(= n 1) s]
    [else    (string-append s " " (string-dup s (sub1 n)))]))
```

Answer (score 1):

When performance matters (e.g. `n` is large), working with lists of characters directly may increase speed significantly. The function `faster-string-dup` below:

- Lines 1-5 perform basic conditional branching as in the accepted answer.
- Line 6 begins a closure over two local values in the `else` clause.
- Lines 7-8 define `s1` which is `string` converted to a list of characters `appended` to a list containing a single character, `#\space`.
- Lines 9-14 define a tail recursive function `next`. It takes two parameters: an integer `n` and a list of characters `acc` and returns a list of characters.
- Line 15 is the trampoline for the `else` clause. It:

  1. Begins the recursive call on the list of characters.
  2. Converts the list of characters returned by the recursive call back to a string.
  3. Appends the original string. This allows `s1` to end with a space rather than begin with one. This is more consistent with our intuitive understanding of the problem - that we add the string and a space for each duplication.

> ```
> 1:  (define (faster-string-dup s n)
>
> 2:   (cond
>
> 3:     [(< n 1) ""]
>
> 4:     [(= n 1) s]
>
> 5:     [else
>
> 6:      (letrec
>
> 7:          ((s1 (append (string->list s)   
>
> 8:                       (list #\space)))
>
> 9:           (next (lambda (n acc)
>
> 10:                  (if (> n 2)
>
> 11:
>
> 12:                  (next (sub1 n)
>
> 13:                            (append s1 acc))
>
> 14:                      acc))))
>
> 15:         (string-append (list->string (next n s1)) s))]))
> ```

Time comparisons using Racket 6.1 from the command line where:

- `string-dup` is the accepted answer
- `duplications` is 10,000
- `dump` is just some mutable variable that prevents lots of screen printing.

Show significantly faster execution compared with the accepted answer.

```
-->(time (set! dump (string-dup "string" duplications)))
cpu time: 1125 real time: 1129 gc time: 262
-->(time (set! dump (faster-string-dup "string" duplications)))
cpu time: 3 real time: 2 gc time: 0
```

The power that Scheme and other Lisps provide by facilitating higher level programming sometimes obscures the fact that Lisps were originally replacements for machine code and can be tuned to run closer to the metal.