# scheme string-reduce when the second element is the concatenation of s n -1 times with spaces in between

Tags: scheme, racket

A following question to 
[scheme string-append? recursion to replicate a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26640743/scheme-string-append-recursion-to-replicate-a-string)

Design a program called string-reduce that consumes a String s and a Number n and produces a list of strings. The resulting list contains n elements, the first element is the concatenation of s n times with spaces in between, the second element is the concatenation of s n -1 times with spaces in between etc. For example

```
(string-reduce "Test" 4) => 
         (cons "Test Test Test Test"
               (cons "Test Test Test" 
                     (cons "Test Test" 
                           (cons "Test" empty))))
```

So i have to do a recursion with n-1 times,

```
(define (string-reduce s n)
(cond
   [(zero? n) empty]
   [else (cons (string-dup s n)
               (string-reduce (string-dup s (sub1 n)) (sub1 n)))]))


(string-reduce "Test" 4) 

(string-dup s n) gives you "s s s.....s" (n times) 

(string-dup s (sub1 n)) gives you "s s s....." (n-1 times)
```

So it should return the example result, instead i have

```
(list
 "Test Test Test Test"
 "Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test"
 "Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test"
 "Test Test Test Test Test Test")
```

Any chance what might be wrong? I suspect the recursion process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your recursive call, you

1. do something for the current value of n (here: call `string-dup`)
2. then do a recursive call to `string-reduce`, decrementing n

There is no need to call `string-dup` again as a parameter of `string-reduce`; the recursive call will take care of this:

```
(define (string-reduce s n)
  (cond
    [(zero? n) empty]
    [else      (cons (string-dup s n)
                     (string-reduce s (sub1 n)))]))
```

Testing:

```
> (string-reduce "Test" 4) 
'("Test Test Test Test" "Test Test Test" "Test Test" "Test")
```